# Changing horizontal JQuery tab into vertical tab

Tags: css, tabs

I have this jquery tab [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Wuw/)
Tabs are showing horizontally. I want to display the tabs vertically and showing the content at the right side .

The original CSS code is

```
.tabs {


background: #c0392b;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabs li {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs a {
  background: #c0392b;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 22px 12px 22px;
  /*border-right: 1px solid @tab-border;*/

}
```

I want to change it in vertical orientation . need help in modifying the css.
I tried to float UL element to the left. but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a CSS solution. Check if this helps you. Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/wekuH/1/)**

Below are the CSS changes made to your css(commented against the changes made).

```
.flat-form {
  /* background: #cd6a60; */ /* Removed this line */ 
  color:#dfdfdf;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding-bottom:20px; */ /* Removed this line */
  position: relative;
    overflow:hidden; /* added this line */
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tabs {
  background: #c0392b;
  /* height: 40px; */ /* Removed this line */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* width: 100%; */ /* Removed this line */
  width: 20%;  /* added this line, change this to whatever value you want the width to be*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* changed block to inline-block */
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */ /* Removed this line */
  float: left; /* Added this line */
}

.tabs li {
  display:block; /* changed inlin-block to block */
  white-space:nowrap;
  /* float: left; */ /* Removed this line */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs a {
  background: #c0392b;
  display: block;
  /* float: left; */ /* Removed this line */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 22px 12px 22px;
  /*border-right: 1px solid @tab-border;*/
    text-align:right; /* added this line */

}
.tabs li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  /* width: 174px; */ /* Removed this line */
  /* padding-left: 0; */  /* Removed this line */
  /* padding-right: 0; */  /* Removed this line */
  /* text-align: center; */ /* Removed this line */
}
.form-action {
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  float:left; /* added this line */
  background: #cd6a60; /* added this line */
  padding:15px; /* added this line */
  width:80%; /* added this line */
  min-height:100px;  /* added this line */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.show {
  display: inline-block; /* changed block to inline-block */
}
```

Also I have made a change in JQuery too, made a comment there also. Please check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical ?

Useing queryui css and add `$( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );`